# How do I get a tooltip to overflow a container?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic tooltip css class I am using,  The problem is, that the tooltip gets clipped by the container it is.  Specifically I am using an angularJs UI Grid and the tool-tip item is in a cell.  The tool-tip does not draw outside of the cell.  I have no idea what I need to change so this tool-tip will draw over everything and not be clipped.

I do have a sample that you can go to see this, if you go to:
[W3schools sample page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_css_internal)

and put in the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .con-tooltip {
      position: relative;
    }
    .con-tooltip:hover:before {
      border: 1px solid #fc0;
      padding: 3px 6px;
      background: #fffea1;
      content: attr(data-title);
      font-size: 1.7em;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: -26px;
      z-index: 999999;
      overflow: visible;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="con-tooltip" data-title="This is a tooltip">This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p class="con-tooltip" data-title="This is a tooltip">This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

If you mouseover the top line of text you will see the tool-tip being clipped by the box, while the bottom line shows the full tool-tip.  What CSS do I need to make the top tooltip show without clipping?

Comment: I like that I can see the issue here in this page.  How do you set it up that way in the first place?  Anyway, if this were working the way I wanted, then the top tool-tip would overlap the box that has the run code snippet box instead of being clipped by it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the tooltip has position absolute and high negative top. You can set a smaller top like:

```css
.con-tooltip {
  position: relative;
}
.con-tooltip:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #fc0;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  background: #fffea1;
  content: attr(data-title);
  font-size: 1.7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;/*set a smaller value for top*/
  z-index: 999999;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<p class="con-tooltip" data-title="This is a tooltip">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="con-tooltip" data-title="This is a tooltip">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

After your comment I will try to solve your issue using `white-space: nowrap;` in class `.con-tooltip`:

```css
.con-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.con-tooltip:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #fc0;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  background: #fffea1;
  content: attr(data-title);
  font-size: 1.7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 999999;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="con-tooltip" data-title="This is a tooltip">This is a paragraph.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="con-tooltip" data-title="This is a tooltip">This is a paragraph.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="con-tooltip" data-title="This is a tooltip">This is a paragraph.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="con-tooltip" data-title="This is a tooltip">This is a paragraph.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not what I asked.  That is just an example.  In the real situation is that I have a tiny cell that has a tool-tip that is MUCH bigger then the cell.  The tool-tip only renders inside the cell and is clipped by the other cells in the table.  I want the entire tool tip to show, appearing over every other HTML element.  Basically it is a 16x16 icon that I want a tool-tip on without using the default title="" because I want something pretty.

Comment: Then please post your relative code. I can't guess what you have in your real project.

Comment: The sample I provided illustrates the problem.  In the grey box that has the "Result:" can you get the tool-tip to display over that? So it overlaps the grey box containing the "sample" ?  If that can be solved, then I am sure my original problem would be solved.

Comment: I checked it on both the example I provided and in my UI Grid, and no, it did not work.  The tool-tips are still contained to the cell.

Comment: Then I will need your html/css.

Comment: Its a huge project.  Is there no way to get the above example to work with just what is provided?  In the Run Code under my original post shows the same problem?  Are you saying that the CSS for the box around the run code snippet will need to change to enable my tool-tip to appear over it? If that is the case, then i may just go back to default tool-tips.

Comment: I don't want your entire project. I want only a piece of code that illustrates your problem.